# Philips Hue Out of home control won't log in

Tags: philips-hue

I have some Philips Hue bulbs and a Bridge set up in my house.

When I am at home the Philips Hue App can connect to and control everything.

However, when I am away from home (or simulate such by turning off WiFi on my phone) the App is unable to connect.

The `Out of home control` section in Settings shows `Not logged in`

I tap it, then the `Log in` button and a browser window opens connecting to api.meethue.com then redirects to account.meethue.com

I sign in to the browser page and am asked to grant permission to the App and I click yes

The `Out of home control` section then says `Logging in...` in orange and a red notification appears saying `Unable to connect`

Eventually, another alert pops up saying `Can't log in to My Hue because the Hue Bridge is offline. Make sure the Hue Bridge is connected to the internet.`

Then the `Out of home control` section reverts to `Not logged in`

The Bridge is definitely connected to the internet - all 3 of the blue LEDs are lit.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I have the same problem on my iPad and on the Hue Labs website

Comment: Can you control it from the web page?

Comment: Which web page?

Comment: There used to be a page accessible from www2.meethue.com but they've changed their site around. There is a page at https://labs.meethue.com, but that won't connect to my bridge at the moment.

Comment: when I try and access the labs page I get this error `It seems that we cannot reach a bridge with the MyHue account you are logged in with. Please make sure your bridge is connected to the internet and to your MyHue account.
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a port issue on my network.

I found a Reddit post which mentioned UPnP and having Port 80 available on the router.

I have a Windows Home Server running on my network which opens up Port 80 via UPnP for some of it's services.

I disabled those services but still couldn't connect via the App or Labs

I restarted the Bridge and can now connect.

So, the answer is - make sure the Bridge can get port 80 on your router.

**EDIT:** I have since re-enabled the Windows Home Server services and both are now playing nicely together!

Comment: The only way around this issue is to enable port 80 on the router?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky As long as your router has UPnP enabled, you shouldn't have to worry about explicitly enabling port 80